# read text file in xcode

Tags: c, macos

i tried to read text file in xcode but this
"EXC_BAD_ACCESS message showed up when i tried to build my program

here is my code
and i put inputA.txt file in the same folder with project file
my friend told me that i should put txt file in debug folder is this why i cannot read txt
file in this code? please help me...

macbook user.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE* fp;  
    char mychar;  
    char arr[50][2] = {0, };  
    int i = 0;  
    int j, k;  
    graphType* G_;  
    G_ = (graphType*)malloc(sizeof(graphType));  
    Create(G_); 
    fp = fopen("inputA.txt", "r");
    //fp = fopen("inputB.txt", "r");
    //fp = fopen("inputC.txt", "r");

    while(1){
        for(j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++){
            mychar = fgetc(fp);
            if(mychar == EOF)
                break;
            else if(mychar == ' ')
                continue;
            arr[i][j] = mychar;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default your binary will be generated in `ProjectDir/build/Mode`, with `Mode` being `Debug` or `Release`, and will have that as its working directory. If you want to refer to a file in the project directory, you'd have to use `../../input.txt` in that case.

The build locations are configured in the *"Build Locations"* section in a targets or projects build tab. The working directory can be manually changed in the settings for the executable (*"General"*, *"Set the working directory to:"*) if needed.

If you are having doubts then you can always find out what the working directory is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    char buf[2048];
    getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `inputA.txt` is not in the same file as the binary.  You should make sure the text file is copied to the output directory in your project (whether manually or by hand).

Also, `fopen` will return `NULL` if the file couldn't be opened, so you might want to add a check for that.

```
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file!");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fopen is probably returning null because your text file isn't in the right place.  Don't forget to check for null!